# Export 3D object with text

Tags: graphics3d, export

I'm trying to Export the 3D object with text in it so that I can adjust it in other software (such as Maya)

```
test=Graphics3D[{Thickness[Large], 
  GraphicsComplex[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {1, 1, 
     2}}, Line[{{1, 2, 5}, {2, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 1, 
      5}}]], {{PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0, 0}], 
    Text["\[CapitalGamma]", {0, 0, 0.2}]}}, Red, Thickness[Large], 
  Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}], Text["\[CapitalSigma]", {1, 1, 0}]}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

the output of above code are following:
[image: the output of above code]

which contain some text. I have tried to Export all the 3D format that Mathematica support

```
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "3D." <> #, test] & /@ {"3ds", "BYU", 
  "JVX", "LWO", "ma", "NOFF", "OBJ", "PLY", "POV", "RIB", "STL", 
  "wrl"}
```

But none of them have text in it, for example

```
Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "3D.JVX"]
```

with output

[image]

the 3D object file seems lost the color, thickness, and text information. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Why not `Export["test.png", test]`?

Comment: Because png format is not 3D object, I want to add other 3D objects with other software.

Comment: I see. thanks for explaining